# Storing Pandas Timestamps from one df and access another df by timestamp

Tags: pandas, numpy, timestamp

I have multiple dataframes in Pandas, all having the same structure. I would like to extract the timestamps of df1 if certain conditions match, then add some time to those timestamps and access df2 by those timestamps. Any ideas that could point me into the right direction?`

```
Timestamp             count    speed
2017-01-01 12:01:00   0        65
2017-01-01 12:02:00   1        82
2017-01-01 12:03:00   0        87
2017-01-01 12:04:00   0        82
2017-01-01 12:05:00   0        81
2017-01-01 12:06:00   1        81

 1. Store Timestamps if count equals 1
t0 = df1.loc[(df.count == 1)].index

 2. Extract Speed of those occurences
v = df1.loc[(df.count == 1)&,'vKfz']

 3. Calculate time travelled
 t1 = s/v

 4. Add t1 to t0 with Time delta t1
 ?

 5. Access another df2 by the new timestamp
 ?
```

Comment: What's wrong with step 4? adding `timedelta` to `timestamp` works nicely.